# Using structs / genetic algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, struct

As practice for myself I'm trying to create a genetic algorithm that will solve equations. So far my program can generate random "genes", fill up individuals with these "genes", and do some basic calculations with the genes (at the moment, simply summing the "genes").

However, I've realised now that I want to implement my fitness function that I would have been better off creating a struct for individual, since I need to keep the genes and the fitness outcome together to have the fittest genes reproduce again.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
// GA.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <string>

const int population_size = 10;
const int number_of_variables = 7;

struct one_individual
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>>individual;;
    double evaluation = 0;
    double fit = 0;
};


int main()
{
// Generate random number

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(-10.0, 10.0);

// Create vector that holds vectors called individual and fill size it to the amount of individuals I want to have.

std::vector<std::vector<double>>individual;

for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    std::vector<double>variables;
    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_variables; j++)
    {
        variables.push_back(dist(rng));
    }
    individual.push_back(variables);
}

// Display entire population

for (auto &count : individual)
{

    for (auto &count2 : count)
    {
        std::cout << count2 << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Do calculation with population. At the moment I just add up all the genes (sum) and display the sum for each individual.


for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    std::cout << "Organism "<< i; 
    double sum = individual[i].at(j) + individual[i].at(j + 1) + individual[i].at(j + 2) + individual[i].at(j + 3) + individual[i].at(j + 4) + individual[i].at(j + 5) + individual[i].at(j + 6);
    std::cout << " is " << sum << "\n";
}

std::cout << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

What I think I should be doing is something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < population_size; i++)
{
    one_individual individual;
    std::vector<double>variables;
    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_variables; j++)
    {
        variables.push_back(dist(rng));
    }
    one_individual.individual.push_back(variables);
}
```

The above code is not working. What happens when I try to compile is I get a list of errors, I just pasted it into pastebin since it's a pretty big list: www.pastebin.com/EVJaV0Ex. If I remove everything except the parts needed for the "creating individuals part" the errors that remain are: www.pastebin.com/djw6JmXZ. All errors are on line 41 which is the final line one_individual.individual.push_back(variables);

Edited for clarity, apologies that it was unclear.

Comment: *"But obviously that's not working"*, no it isn't obvious. Why isn't it working? Is it not compiling, if not what is the exact error you get? If you are not getting the correct runtime behavior describe your problem with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What happens when I try to compile is I get a list of errors, I just pasted it into pastebin since it's a pretty big list: http://pastebin.com/EVJaV0Ex. If I remove everything except the parts needed for the "creating individuals part" the errors that remain are: http://pastebin.com/djw6JmXZ. All errors are on line 41 which is the final line one_individual.individual.push_back(variables); 

Does that make it clearer? Added it into my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the instruction

```
one_individual.individual.push_back(variables);
```

where `one_individual` is a **type** (`struct one_individual`).

I suppose you should use the defined **variable** of type `one_individual`, so

```
individual.individual.push_back(variables);
```